# Kubernetes Ingress on server side deployment

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, iptables, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

#### Wanted scenario:

Given a virtual machine, with device IP `192.168.2.22`.  Run Kubernetes with minikube on it, serve API apps with ingress, services, and deployments. (minikube IP = ingress IP = `172.17.0.2` in the device)

And then expected to access these APIs / server from other PCs.

Here would like to ask about how can this scenario be fulfilled?  Hope someone can share their experiences & wisdom.  Even some simple keywords may help.

#### Tried

My idea was to map `172.17.0.2` to the `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` on the device (with `iptable`), but then it turned out that the ingress actually needs the `host.name.com` string to work, so this failed.

#### Ingress description

```
Name:             my-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          172.17.0.2
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  localhost
              /route1/?(.*)   service1 (172.18.0.4:80)
              /route2/?(.*)   service2 (172.18.0.4:80)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) you should be able to add the following line to the bottom of the `/etc/hosts` file.

> Note: If you are running Minikube locally, use minikube ip to get the
> external IP. The IP address displayed within the ingress list will be
> the internal IP.

```
 <MINIKUBE-EXTERNAL-IP> host.name.com
```

Then you can do curl `host.name.com`

2. Alternatively use `xip.io` wildcard DNS where `172.17.0.2.xip.io` resolves to `172.17.0.2`